# How to do the filter element button style in css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have the button in different style when click on the table filter button.
Just like the "individual" button style.
[image: example]
When I click "Team", I want the that button have same style as "individual" button shown.

Here is my css code.

```
table{
  border-spacing:0px 0px; 
  width: 100%;
  color:#565454;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
table th,table tr td{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
        border-left: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
        border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
        height:50px;        
    font-size:20px;
    }
th{
        font-size:20px;
        color:white;
        font-weight:lighter;
    }
    thead{
        background:var(--darkgreen);
        height:50px;
    }
td:nth-child(2){
        text-align:center;
        padding:0 10px;
        font-size:20px;
    }
    td:nth-child(3){
        text-align:center;
        padding:0 10px;
        font-size:20px;
    }
    td:nth-child(3){
        
        font-size:20px;
    }
  tbody td{
    color:var(--black);
    text-align:center;
    height:50px;
  }
  .btn{
    background-color:lightgray;
    border:none;
    color:var(--black);
    font-size:16px;
    padding:0 1em;
    margin:1em 0.5em
  }

.btn.active{
    background-color:white;
    border: orange 1px solid;

}
```

Here is my coldfusion code.

```
<div class="relative" style="display:flex;flex-direction: row;align-items: center;justify-content: flex-end;">
     <br>
     <br>
        <p align="right" style="max-width:100%;font-size:20px;">Filter by: 
        <div id="myBtnContainer">
            <button class="btn active"  onClick="window.location = 'leaderboard.cfm?type=Individual';filterSelection('Individual')">Individual</button>
            <button class="btn"  onClick="window.location = 'leaderboard.cfm?type=Team';filterSelection('Team')">Team</button>
            <button class="btn"  onClick="window.location = 'leaderboard.cfm?type=Community';filterSelection('Community')">Community</button>
            <button class="btn"  onClick="window.location = 'leaderboard.cfm?type=Organization';filterSelection('Organization')">Organization</button>
        </div>
        </p>
    </div>
```

```
<table style="width:100%; border:solid 1px #DDD;" class="leaderboard-table">    
<cfif url.type eq 'Individual'> 
        <thead>

  <!---Individual----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
          <tr style="background-color:#3e6934; color:white; text-align:center;height:100px;" class="filterDiv Individual">
            <th style="width:80px">Rank</th>
            <th style="width:210px">Name</th>
            <th style="width:50px">Level</th>
            <th style="width:120px">Community</th>
            <th>Organization</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th style="width:80px">Action Points</th>
            <th style="width:80px">Knowledge Points</th>
            <th style="width:80px">Carbon Credits</th>
            <th style="width:80px">Total Points</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
<tr leader-board-individual data--member-id="#Individual.id#">
                <td leaderboard-counter></td>
                <td align="left">#name#</td>
                <td><span class="leader-board-user_level"></span></td>
                
                <td align="left">#Individuals_Team.Location#</td>
                <td align="left">#Individuals_Team.Parent_Organization_Name#</td>
                <td align="left">#Individuals_Team.name#</td>
                
                <td><span class="leader-board-action_points"></span></td>
                <td><span class="leader-board-knowledge_points"></span></td>
                <td><span class="leader-board-carbon_credits"></span></td>
                <td><span class="leader-board-total_points"></span></td>
              </tr>
<cfelseif url.type eq 'Team'>
<thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#3e6934; color:white; text-align:center;height:100px;" class="filterDiv Team">
            <th style="width:80px">Rank</th>           
            <th style="width:250px">Team</th>
            <th>Green Certified Organization</th>
            <th>Community</th>
            <th>Members</th>
            <th style="width:80px">Total Action Points</th>
            <th style="width:80px">Total Knowledge Points</th>
            <th style="width:80px">Total Carbon Credits</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>  
<tr leader-board-team data--member-id="#Individual.id#">
            <td leaderboard-counter></td>
                <td align="left"></td>
                <td align="left"></td>
                
                <td align="left"></td>
                <td align="left"></td>
                
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
    
              </tr>
```

Here is the javascript code I copid from W3school.

```
filterSelection("Individual")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "Individual") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

Add a data attribute to the buttons in the HTML, which is referred in the onclick function

```html
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" data-index='1' onClick="filterSelection('Individual',1)">Individual</button>
  <button class="btn" data-index='2' onClick="filterSelection('Team',2)">Team</button>
  <button class="btn" data-index='3' onClick="filterSelection('Community',3)">Community</button>
  <button class="btn" data-index='4' onClick="filterSelection('Organization',4)">Organization</button>
</div>
```

This JS function will cause the state of the buttons to be toggled on click, it is up to you to then add functionality to perform the necessary action.

```js
function toggleActiveState(c, index) {
  const element = document.querySelector(".btn[data-index='"+index+"']")
  element.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

This bit of code does not appear to be required if the above function is used as it interferes with the button state.

```js
// var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
// var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
// for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
//   btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
//     var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
//     current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
//     this.className += " active";
//   });
// }
```

Comment: I tried your code. But the button style still doesn't change. Do I need to edit anything in the ><table> or <cfif url.type eq 'Individual'> ?

Comment: You need to edit the buttons to add the data attribute - `data-index='#'`, this is in the div with the ID `myBtnContainer`. See the top part of my post.

Comment: I added the data attribute. But if I delete the window.location.........in the button div: onClick="window.location = 'leaderboard.cfm?type=Individual';filterSelection('Individual')">- the button style is good. But I cannot go to different table.

Comment: So if the page will change (via `window.location`) then it would be better to add the parameter into a query variable. e.g. `leaderboard.cfm?type=Individual,Team,Community`, then when the page changes, you can read the query variable, separate the values by comma and then apply styles as necessary. Unfortunately I am not well versed in coldfusion, so I can't say exactly how to do that. But these are the steps I would imagine you would end up taking